# adding leading zeros to decimal to binary array C

Tags: c, binary, decimal, zero

I am converting decimal to binary and I need my output to be 32 (bits?) long. This works as I intend, but I am not getting the leading zeros, for instance, the input "3" gives me "11", instead of "00000000000000000000000000000011"

```
    int i = 0;
    int bi[31];

    while(num > 0){
        if(num % 2 == 0)
            bi[i] = 0;
        else
            bi[i] = 1;
        i++;
        num = num / 2;
    }
    for(int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--){
        printf("%d", bi[j]);
    }
```

I originally thought this would be as simple as changing my printout to just loop down from 31 to 0 and print out all the contents of the array, assuming zeros would be in everything not in my bi[] array. But that does not work :)

Thanks

Comment: If you want a 32-bit binary value, why do you have space for only 31 bits?

Comment: What is "num" ? Ahow your code properly..... otherwise how someone help you ?

Comment: I used 31 because this is my first C class and Im used to making a 32 position array in java, type [31]... Num i thought would be pretty obviously the number I converted to binary. Next time I will be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int j = 0; j < 32; j++) // this for loop is initializing all the places with zeroes
{ 
    b[j] = 0;
}
i = 31 // starting from the leftmost place of the array
while(num > 0) //as the values in the array gets updated the remaining place is left with trailing 
{
    if(num % 2 == 0)
        bi[i] = 0;
    else
        bi[i] = 1;
    i--;
    num = num / 2;
} zeroes
for(int j = 0; j < 32; j++){
    printf("%d", bi[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Due to the LIFO nature of this problem, consider a recursive (stack-based) solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void recFoo(int num,int index)
{
    if (index > 0)
        recFoo(num/2, index-1);
    printf("%d", num%2);
}

void foo(int num)
{
    recFoo(num, sizeof(num)*CHAR_BIT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reson is because the first loop only loops twice, which is the highest set bit in the input. The first loop needs to loop *unconditionally* the number of bits you want, and so should the printing loop.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a 32 long array. Try this one..... Initializing your array

```
void foo (int num) {
int i = 31;
int bi[32] = {0};

while(num > 0){
    if(num % 2 == 0)
        bi[i] = 0;
    else
        bi[i] = 1;
    i--;
    num = num / 2;
}
for(int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--){
    printf("%d", bi[j]);
}
```